# Android Studio doesn't always wrap when hard wrap is set

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've been having trouble with code formatting in Android Studio. Even when every option in Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > Wrapping and Braces is set to "Wrap if long" or "Chop down if long", it doesn't always wrap long lines when I run Reformat Code/File (Ctrl+Alt[+Shift]+L). Same with Java.

For example, with "Hard wrap at: 30", try the following lines:

```kotlin
// 30 characters ends here: ||
internal const val myLongVariableName: Boolean =
    true

fun foo(someVal: Int) : Int {
    System.out.println("Hello world!")
    if (someVal > 123456 && someVal < 123456) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Android Studio refuses to wrap these lines further. Whereas I would expect something like:

```kotlin
// 30 characters ends here: ||
internal const val
        myLongVariableName
        : Boolean = true

fun foo(someVal: Int): Int {
    System.out.println(
        "Hello world!")
    if (someVal > 123456
        && someVal < 123456) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, Android Studio will actually convert the 2nd example into the 1st, non-wrapped example when reformatting unless "Keen when reformatting: Line breaks" is checked!

Even with a more realistic line length of 100, I run into this a lot with log statements.